# Android Studio 2.1.2 is not creating the R.java file for my application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

JDK-8 UPDATE 91
Android Studio 2.1.2

Not creating the R.java file
[Not recognizing the R file and i am not able to find it in project view left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbdfM.png)

[Giving these error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzAKm.png)

Comment: You have an error somewhere in your XML or you are using a library/sdk version that you don't have set or installed.

Comment: @basic i have no error in my xml file you can see it by clicking on the below link http://i.stack.imgur.com/UzGtw.png

Comment: Can you add your manifest.xml file please.

Comment: @basic but i am not understanding what you are saying about sdk can please explain

Comment: Can you add your manifest.xml file and build.gradle file. Please don't link an image and if you do just put it in the body of your question.

Comment: @basic AndroidManiFest.xml file

Comment: @basic http://i.stack.imgur.com/4aO7X.png

Comment: Add your build.gradle file.

Comment: @basic build.gradle file http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQwbz.png

Comment: please font paste screenshots of your code instead of posting the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you are using appcompat-v7:23.4.0 but your build tools version is for 19.1.0. You need to upgrade your buildToolsVersion or downgrade your support library version (not the optimal solution).

Change the line:

```
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

You may need to install this build tools version, alternatively as I said you can downgrade your support library version as well.